# Using pip on Anaconda installation-Windows 11-deprecated usage of EasyInstall

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm trying to install a package that hasn't been updated recently and it looks like it used EasyInstall to build the wheel and now it fails because EasyInstall was deprecated.

The error message is below and it appears to have solutions-I believe I need to specify the install directory for the wheel. However, I'm unsure what to specify for the installation directory or where to specify it.  I have created an env to run this in. I have searched for the build directory within my windows username and can't find it.

Thanks

```
C:\Users\bart.GEOMETRICS\.conda\envs\geophpy\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
              standards-based tools.

              See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      Checking .pth file support in build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\
      C:\Users\bart.GEOMETRICS\.conda\envs\geophpy\pythonw.exe -E -c pass
      TEST FAILED: build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\ does NOT support .pth files
      bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

      You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
      on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
      installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
      the distutils default setting) was:

          build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\

      and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

          ''

      Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

      * You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
        on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

      * You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
        variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
        Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

      * You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
        using one of the approaches described here:

        https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations
```

I tried the -target option to specify an install directory and it still failed.

Comment: What was the command that you ran?

Comment: Can you install other packages with `pip`?

Comment: I ran "pip install geophpy", I have installed several other packages with pip and have had no issues.